# Selecting previous element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Trying to select the previous h4 with jquery. Basically I have something like this:

```
<h4>THING I WANT 1</h4>
<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>
<button>Three</button>

<h4>THING I WANT 2</h4>
<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>
<button>Three</button>

<h4>THING I WANT 3</h4>
<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>
<button>Three</button>
```

And in my javascript, when one of the buttons is clicked I'm trying to select **only** the h4 text directly before that button with:

```
$(this).prev("h4").text(),
```

This works for the first button (I'm guessing because it's immediately following the h4) but not for the subsequent buttons. `prevAll` is not the answer (because it selects all previous H4s) so I'm getting a bit confused.

Using the logic of $(selector).filter() my approach seems sensible to me. Would appreciate any help. I'm happy to wrap the above in a div or something if that helps.

Comment: Could you show more code?

Comment: `.prevAll()` **is** the answer assuming you want any of the buttons to change your `<h4>`. Can you please add more context (and possibly code) to explain exactly what you're trying to do, and why `.prevAll()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: prevAll returns all previous H4s as opposed to only the one previous one. The page has multiple copies of the H4+button set seen above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prevAll` is indeed the answer, but you have to select the first element in the collection, otherwise *all* previous `h4`s will be included:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  const $h4s = $(this).prevAll("h4");
  console.log($h4s[0].textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>THING I WANT 1</h4>
<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>
<button>Three</button>

<h4>THING I WANT 2</h4>
<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>
<button>Three</button>

<h4>THING I WANT 3</h4>
<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>
<button>Three</button>
```

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted, this works nicely. Required a few extra lines but it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The easist will be to use `prevAll`.

[**Sample JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hkz105ns/6/)

**HTML:**

```
  <h4>THING I WANT</h4>
 <button>One</button>
 <button>Two</button>
 <button>Three</button>
```

**Script**

```
$('button').on('click', function()
 {
    var txt= $(this).prevAll('h4').text();
    alert(txt);
 });
```

Comment: This does not work because OP has multiple `h4`s in the container.